# Perl: sort hash ref using multiple array ref values

Tags: sorting, perl, hash, cmp, arrayref

I have a hash ref with values being an array ref. I would like to sort the hash using multiple values. For example:

```perl
{ 'ID' => ['Age', 'Name', 'Start-Date'] }
```

I would like to sort by: 1) `Age`; then-by by 2) `Start-Date` (if `Age`s are equal). [For example](https://onecompiler.com/perl/3yd7agy35):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $r = {
    'QX' => ['17','Jack','2022-05-31'],
    'ZE' => ['19','Jill','2022-05-31'],
    'RW' => ['17','Aida','2022-08-23'],
    'FX' => ['19','Bill','2022-05-23'],
    'IR' => ['16','Dave','2022-04-01']
};

for my $key (sort {$r->{$a}-[0] <=> $r->{$b}-[0] or $r->{$a}-[2] cmp $r->{$b}-[2]} keys %{$r}) {
    say STDERR "$key: $r->{$key}->[0] : $r->{$key}->[2] : $r->{$key}->[1]";
}
```

The code above, however, yields incosistent reults.

My expected output (sort by `Age` followed-by `Start-Date`) would be:

```
IR: 16 : 2022-04-01 : Dave
QX: 17 : 2022-05-31 : Jack
RW: 17 : 2022-08-23 : Aida
FX: 19 : 2022-05-23 : Bill
ZE: 19 : 2022-05-31 : Jill
```

Comment: What is `{$a}-[0]` (etc), with a hyphen ?  Do you mean `{$a}->[0]` (with an arrow)?

Comment: @h q: In what place you expect `RW: 17 : 2022-08-23 : Aida` to be printed? Since you mentioned first priority is for `Age` and second is for `Start-Date`.

Comment: Your code is all good, as are the results, once you replace (the typo?) hyphen by the correct arrow...  The funny thing is that it runs, and produces results, even with that (non-sensical typo of) hyphen!

Comment: Voted to close as a typo

Comment: I am so sorry @zdim. Thank you!

Comment: @hq  All is well, nothing to worry about :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
$r->{$a}-[0]
```

should be

```perl
$r->{$a}->[0]
```

or just

```perl
$r->{$a}[0]   # Arrow optional between indexes.
```

---

You could also use

```perl
use Sort::Key::Multi qw( uskeysort );

uskeysort { $r->{ $_ }->@[ 0, 2 ] } keys %$r
```